# How do you define/substitute $.variable_values in a CloudFormation template for a StepFunctions StateMachine?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-step-functions

I've created a step-function involving 2 lambdas and a choice already, and I'd basically like to create a CloudFormation resource referencing that, or a CloudFormation resource that I can just paste in the definition of my existing step function. I've been searching and found that you seemingly can just paste in the definition of your step function for the DefinitionString property; the problem with that is I use a lot of substitutions/"$" in my definition. I see that some examples are replacing their "$" values with curly braces, but I was wondering if that's required?

Here's one example:

```
"ResultSelector":{"start_date.$":"$.Payload.body.payload[0]","end_date.$":"$.Payload.body.payload.[1]"
```

Would I have to replace even the Keys with curly braces? Also, would I have to get rid of the prefixing "." before the rest of the value? I guess I'm basically asking for an example of how I'd properly replace this code snippet for a YAML template

Answer (score 0):

You probably do not want to use the DefinitionString property, as that requires you to "stringify" your JSON object.

You probably want to use the [Definition property](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-stepfunctions-statemachine.html#cfn-stepfunctions-statemachine-definition). This allows you to provide the definition for your state machine in the same format as the rest of your template. You can see [an example of this here](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-stepfunctions-examples/blob/main/sam/demo-asl-features/template.yaml).

Also, [Workflow Studio](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/workflow-studio.html) makes it easy to export your definition to either JSON or YAML to help with this.

[image]

You can also keep your state machine definition separate from your template using the [DefinitionS3Location](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-stepfunctions-statemachine.html#cfn-stepfunctions-statemachine-definitions3location) property, however this is most easily accomplished using [AWS SAM](https://aws.amazon.com/serverless/sam/) and the `AWS::Serverless::StateMachine`. It has a [DefintionUri property](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-resource-statemachine.html#sam-statemachine-definitionuri) which will guide the [SAM CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/install-sam-cli.html) to take care of the deployment work of uploading your externalized definition file to S3 and using it. You can see [an example of doing so here](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-stepfunctions-examples/blob/main/sam/demo-bulk-delete-s3-objects/template.yaml).